# Add input above table

Tags: html, css

How you can see in my HTML i have two tables. Now i would like to add inputs after each table:

1.Shows how my Html looked without the `span`s and the `input`s

2.Shows how it looks now: http://jsfiddle.net/tLHSB/2/

3.How i would like to have it

[image]

Thanks for your help!

My HTML:

```
<span>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size:13px; width:50px; float:left;" id="ScheinDiagnosen">
  <thead>
    <tr id="DiagnosenButton">
       <th>Number1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="DiagnosenBlock"  style="background-color: red">    
      <tr class="sanD"><td>H26.2</td></tr>
      <tr class="sanD"><td>H90.2</td></tr>
      <tr class="sanD"><td>B01.1</td></tr>
      <tr class="sanDD"><td>B01.1</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
  <input style="width:10px; display:block">
</span>
<span>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size:13px; width:50px; float: left;" id="ScheinEbms">
  <thead>
    <tr id="EBMButton">
       <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="EbmBlock" style="background-color: blue;">

  <tr><td>02401</td></tr>
  <tr><td>02400</td></tr>
  <tr><td>03322</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  <input style="width:10px;display:block"> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're floating your tables, which causes them to break out of the document flow. There are a few ways to accomplish what you want, but try replacing the `span` elements with `div`s and float them instead of the tables.

Also, don't use inline styles, use a block of CSS. It'll make your code more maintainable in the long run.

Replacing your `span`s with `div`s, and removing inline styles, your new CSS would look like:

```
table {
    font-size:13px;
    width:50px;
}
#DiagnosenBlock {
    background-color: red;
}
#EbmBlock {
    background-color: blue;
}
div {
    float: left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/tLHSB/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css :

```
span {
    float:left;
}
```

And remove `float:left` from your `table` style.

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/tLHSB/5/

Comment: Your code doesn't currently top-align the tables as specified.